# GraphQL unexcepted error Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, graphql

soy algo nuevo desplegando APIs en Azure, desplegue una API de GraphQl hecha en C# en .NET 7  con Hot chocolate y tengo el siguiente problema, en local todas queries y mutations funcionan perfectamente, pero cuando lo pruebo desde Azure algunas mutations como queries me marcan unexcepeted error, teniendo en cuenta que el mismo codigo que tengo en local se esta ejecutando en la nube
Me sale lo siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta que es a que se debe, estoy con el plan gratis de Azure que es el cual uso, tengo decir que tengo unas 30 mutations y queries, si por el uso de CPU y si no habra alguna manera de obtener los errores mas especificios de GraphQl, gracias :)